# "sudo" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: command-line

I am trying to install reaver but every time I write `sudo -s` I get this message at the end

```
"sudo" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you append your question to include the output of `uname -a`, and are you running bash in Windows?

Answer (score 7):

The phrase

```
... is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Is specific to Windows. That is to say, you're at a Windows command prompt.

Use Ubuntu. You'll find your commands work slightly better there.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo` is a Unix command to carry out a task as superuser.
By the phrase "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.", I can already tell that you are using Windows.
Run `sudo` on Ubuntu. You are in a Q&A forum for Ubuntu users.